# Define zoom/pan start position with KenBurnsView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-kenburnsview

I'm working with the library [KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView/issues) and I have a problem:

the overview or this nice library says the following: "Highly extensible: you can define how the rectangles to be zoomed and panned will be generated"
and that's exactly what I want to do but I don't know exactly how.

I would like to be able to tell the library to zoom or pan from a specified region (a RectF I presume) of my image.
I think I have to implements my own TransitionGenerator and write a custom generateNextTransition() mtehod but I don't know what to do inside.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks.
Adrian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement your own `TransitionGenerator` and override `generateNextTransition()` from where you must return a `Transition` object.

The `generateNextTransition()` method takes:

1. `RectF drawableBounds`: the bounds of the drawable that is set to the `KenBurnsView`;
2. `RectF viewport` the bounds of the `KenBurnsView` object.

The `Transition` constructor takes:

1. `RectF srcRect`: a subrectangle of the drawable that will fill the whole `KenBurnsView` when the transition starts (illustrated below):

[image: Ken Burns effect]

*Illustration from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_effect)*

2. `RectF dstRect`: a subrectangle of the drawable that will fill the whole `KenBurnsView` when the transition ends;
3. `long duration`: the duration, in milliseconds, of the transition.
4. `Interpolator interpolator`: an interpolator instance that will define the nature of the movement (may be an `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator`, `LinearInterpolator`, etc.);

It might me a good idea to save `dstRect` to be used as `srcRect` in the next transition if you desire that every transition will start from the place the last transition has stopped. That's exactly what the `RandomTransitionGenerator` does. Keep in mind that `srcRect` and `dstRect` can have different sizes (but both should be subrectangles of `drawableBounds` if you want to keep the image in scene all the time). It's important that both of them have the same aspect ratio of `viewport`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Flávio!
The customer needs on this project have changed so I will not integrate this solution at this time but I'll definitly use it on some other app.