# Animate Matrix in ImageView

Tags: android, animation, matrix, imageview, scale

Is there any way to animate changing of scale type in an `ImageView`? For example, I have the image with `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP`, and I want to create an animation when the image inside animates to `ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER`. I saw the source code of [ChangeImageTransform](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/transition/ChangeImageTransform.java) but I can't figure out how can I do that in my code.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535954/animate-scaletype-centercrop-in-imageview

Comment: Oh, yes I have, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: the only way is to set `scaleType=matrix` and scale / translete the `Matrix` accordingly

Comment: @thyago Okay, it seems the first option works for me now. However, what if I want to animate scaling/translation of the `ImageView` using `ObjectAnimator`, does it affect the animation with `Matrix`? I want to use both of them at the same time. Let's say the matrix animation works with the image inside, I work with the real view.

Comment: so if you want `ObjectAnimator` then simply use `ObjectAnimator#ofObject(Object target, String propertyName, TypeEvaluator evaluator, Object... values)` where `values` are two or more `Rect` objects, `Rect` is the proffered type as there is a built-in `TypeEvaluator` for it

Comment: Yes, I know how to handle the matrix animation, but I don't get a desired behavior when I try to animate both the  image matrix and bounds of the `ImageView`. To make it clear, I have two `ImageView`s  and every one of them has a different position on the screen and scale type. First of all, I set the bounds of the first `ImageView` to the second, and from that point I start animating the second view to its final position on the screen. During this animation I'm also doing the  matrix animation in order to change smoothly the scale types.And all that thing doesn't give me an appropriate result