# Fit image to entire imageView then animate to show the hidden part

Tags: android, android-animation, android-kenburnsview

What I'm trying to obtain is when loading an image from the imageView it should fill the whole imageview similar to scaleType="centerCrop" but instead of cropping it in the center it should crop to the left if it's a landscape image or crop to top if portriat. Then it should pan slowly to display the cropped part of the image slowly.

Like this illustration.

[image]

I found a library that might help me with this dilemma

[KenburnsView](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView)

The only problem is that documentation does not give a comprehensive explanation regarding the `TransitionGenerator` which is what I need and I am too dumb to figure it out myself. I tried googling around but was able to find only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958739/define-zoom-pan-start-position-with-kenburnsview).

If you have tried this library can you point me to the right direction or if you have other library with a similar feature please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need in the APP I recently work on.

After reading the source code of [KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView), here
is a workable `TransitionGenerator`:

```
public static class ScanTransitionGenerator implements TransitionGenerator {
    private static final int DEFAULT_TRANSITION_DURATION = 5000;
    private static final Interpolator DEFAULT_TRANSITION_INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();

    private long transitionDuration;
    private Interpolator transitionInterpolator;
    private Transition lastTransition;
    private RectF lastDrawableBounds;
    private boolean forward;

    public ScanTransitionGenerator() {
        transitionDuration = DEFAULT_TRANSITION_DURATION;
        transitionInterpolator = DEFAULT_TRANSITION_INTERPOLATOR;
    }

    @Override
    public Transition generateNextTransition(RectF drawableBounds, RectF viewport) {
        float drawableRatio = getRectRatio(drawableBounds);
        float viewportRectRatio = getRectRatio(viewport);
        RectF startRect;
        RectF endRect;
        if (drawableRatio >= viewportRectRatio) {
            float w = drawableBounds.height() * viewportRectRatio;
            float h = drawableBounds.height();
            startRect = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
            endRect = new RectF(drawableBounds.width() - w, 0, drawableBounds.width(), h);
        } else {
            float w = drawableBounds.width();
            float h = drawableBounds.width() / viewportRectRatio;
            startRect = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
            endRect = new RectF(0, drawableBounds.height() - h, w, drawableBounds.height());
        }

        if (!drawableBounds.equals(lastDrawableBounds) || !haveSameAspectRatio(lastTransition.getDestinyRect(), viewport)) {
            forward = false;
        }
        forward = !forward;

        if (forward) {
            lastTransition = new Transition(startRect, endRect, transitionDuration, transitionInterpolator);
        } else {
            lastTransition = new Transition(endRect, startRect, transitionDuration, transitionInterpolator);
        }

        lastDrawableBounds = new RectF(drawableBounds);
        return lastTransition;
    }

    private static boolean haveSameAspectRatio(RectF r1, RectF r2) {
        return (Math.abs(getRectRatio(r1) - getRectRatio(r2)) <= 0.01f);
    }

    private static float getRectRatio(RectF rect) {
        return rect.width() / rect.height();
    }
}
```